# how do i check under which username a script is run?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

i have this script:

```
BACKUP DATABASE timeclockplus TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\Backup\backup.bak'
```

how do i know which username is executing it? the reason i ask is because i want to grant extra privelages to the current username so that instead of writing that backup folder i can write to a different folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no context as such except for sa *inside* the DB engine.

Based on your recent questions, you mean *external* SQL Server context which will be the service account used (you can see it in Services.msc). So if you are using `domain\Specialuser` then you could permission `domain\Specialuser` on a folder.

However, SQL Server 2005 introduced some groups that should contain the service account specified at install time and these should be used for external (eg outside SQL Server) permissions

Some details in [KB 283811](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283811) , but best seeing "[Reviewing Windows NT Rights and Privileges Granted for SQL Server Service Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#Review_NT_rights)". The groups mentioned here are what you should permission on your desired folder.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`SUSER_SNAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174427.aspx).

(That page is a bit misleading, passing no param returns the current user - either an SQL Logon or a domain\user depending on the auth mode)

Comment: @Andomar: Because it's wrong answer for this question which says "...instead of writing that backup folder i can write to a different folder". So it's about the SQL Service account, not the DB engine current user. And it's my downvote because of this. Unless you know something I don't about how SUSER_SNAME() relates to NFTS permissions

Comment: @gbn: Looks like you're right!  Perhaps a comment to explain would be better than a downvote that looks puzzling at first sight :)